# loading and dynamic linking

Tags: dynamic, linker, libraries, shared, libc

When a process requires a function from a dynamic library, is the whole library loaded into memory or just the function alone is loaded?

For example:
When I use the `printf()` or any function from the libc (assuming it is a dynamic library), is the whole libc loaded into memory or just the `printf()` function alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the whole library loaded into memory or just the function alone is loaded?

The answer depends on what exactly you mean by "loaded into memory", and on which operating system you are running your program.

Let's consider Linux, and typical linking against `libc.so`.

There, the entire `PT_LOAD` segments containing `.data` and `.text` of `libc.so.6` are `mmap()`ed into memory before the first instruction of your program even executes (because your program records that it *needs* `libc.so.6` in its `.dynamic` section).

From then on, the code is *demand paged* into RAM, when you access it. When you call `printf`, the pages that contain code for `printf` are paged in from disk, or (more likely) reused from the buffer cache.

Comment: by "disk" ( "paged in from disk" ) u mean RAM  or swap.

Comment: @vanangamudi Please use whole words, like "you" instead of "u". No, by "disk" I mean this kind of disk: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_platter